# $(document).on("click" .. this and then that element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 1 checkbox and 2 radio button options.

When `wedding` is selected from the checkbox and `boys` is selected from the first radio option, I want to then display another radio option container under that class `.coaches`.

I've read the correct way is to separate them with comma, which I have done:

`$(document).on("click",'#wedding, #boys', function() {`

But it doesn't work.

Basically, show `.coaches` on if both of them are checked or marked.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.coaches').hide();

$(document).on("click",'#wedding, #boys', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.coaches').show();
    $('.coaches').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.coaches').hide();
    $('.coaches').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="wedding" name="wedding" value="Wedding">
<label for="wedding">Wedding</label>

<input type="radio" id="boys" name="rep" value="boys">
<span>Boys</span>

<div class="coaches">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).is(':checked')` checks if that particular element is checked - you need to check both;

```js
$('.coaches').hide();
  
$(document).on("click",'#wedding, input[name=rep]',function(){
  if ($('#wedding').is(':checked') && $('#boys').is(':checked')) {
    $('.coaches').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.coaches').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">. 
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="wedding" name="wedding" value="Wedding">
<label for="wedding">Wedding</label>

<input type="radio" id="boys" name="rep" value="boys">
<span>Boys</span>

<input type="radio" id="girl" name="rep" value="girls">
<span>Girl</span>

<div class="coaches">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: `fadeIn()` chained to `show()` doesn't make sense. Can't fade something in that is already visible

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, I combined both lines together without removing `show()`.

Comment: Thanks, I can see it working, however, if (once `.coaches` is visible) the user selects another radio option, then `.coaches` is still visible. For example, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bk4orswy/1/ Check `wedding` and then select `boys` and`.coaches` will be visible. Now change from boys to girls, `.coaches` is still visible

Comment: Because the new radio button doesn't fire the event. I changed the selector to fire on all elements that match `input[name=rep]`.